# Is there a way to get *app_remove* events count from firebase using node js

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-admin, google-analytics-4

I'm interested in tracking the number of uninstalls for my app. I have observed that uninstalls are recorded as "app_remove" events in Firebase Analytics. However, I would like to programmatically retrieve the count of these events using Node.js or Python. Is there a method or API available for this purpose?

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

I have tried below code but it is always saying admin.analytis is undefined. Although I have initialized the firebase admin-sdk correctly and already using it for sending push notifications to users.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
admin.initializeApp(adminConfigs);

// Get the Firebase Analytics instance.
const analytics = admin.analytics();

// Get the app_remove event data.
const appRemoveEvents = await analytics.event('app_remove').get();

// Process the app_remove event data.
for (const event of appRemoveEvents) {
  // Get the user's ID.
  const userId = event.user.userId;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node) there is no `analytics` component in there, so that explains why the code you wrote doesn't work.

To get reporting data out of Google Analytics, you can use the [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)
. There are [SDKs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries) available for many platforms, including Node.js and Python.